# $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are solution of $a \cdot \tan\theta + b \cdot \sec\theta = c$ show $ \tan(\alpha + \beta) = \frac{2ac}{a^2 - c^2}$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the solution of $$a \cdot \tan\theta + b \cdot \sec\theta = c$$, then show that $$ \tan(\alpha + \beta) = \frac{2ac}{a^2 - c^2}$$

I did the following:

> $$a \cdot \tan\theta + b \cdot \sec\theta = c$$
>
> Squaring both sides,  $$a^2 \cdot \tan^2\theta + b^2 \cdot \sec \theta + 2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot \tan \theta \cdot \sec \theta = c^2$$
>
> This implies $$(a^2 + b^2) \cdot \sin^2 \theta + 2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot \sin \theta + (b^2 - c^2) = 0$$
>
> Hence I get $$\sin \alpha + \sin \beta = \frac{-2ab}{a^2 + c^2}$$ and $$\sin \alpha \cdot \sin \beta = \frac{b^2 - c^2}{a^2 - c^2}$$

But I am not able to solve it further.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813364/trigonometrical-solve, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805602/how-to-to-a-better-approach-for-this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following:

\begin{align*}
c-a\tan \theta & = b \sec \theta\\
(c-a\tan \theta)^2 & = (b\sec \theta)^2\\
 (a^2-b^2)\tan^2 \theta -2ac \tan \theta+(c^2-b^2) & = 0.
\end{align*}
Think of this as a quadratic in $\tan \theta$. It has two solutions $\tan \alpha$ and $\tan \beta$. So 
\begin{align*}
 \tan \alpha + \tan \beta & = \frac{2ac}{a^2-b^2}\\
 \tan \alpha \cdot \tan \beta & = \frac{c^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2}
\end{align*}
Now you can compute using
$$\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\tan \alpha +\tan\beta}{1-\tan \alpha \tan \beta}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using [Double-Angle Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html),

$$\sec\theta=\dfrac{1+t^2}{1-t^2},\tan\theta=\dfrac{2t}{1-t^2}$$  where $t=\tan\dfrac\theta2$ to form a Quadratic Equation in $t$ whose roots will be $$\tan\dfrac\alpha2,\tan\dfrac\beta2$$

Can you find $$\tan\left(\dfrac\alpha2+\dfrac\beta2\right)$$  and subsequently, $$\tan(\alpha+\beta)$$