# A Trigonometric Question

Tags: trigonometry

If

$$\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(\theta\right)}+\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\sin\left(\theta\right)}\:=1=\:\frac{\cos\left(y\right)}{\cos\left(\theta\right)}+\frac{\sin\left(y\right)}{\sin\left(\theta\right)}\:\:$$

Then what's the value of :

$$\frac{\cos\left(x\right)\:\cos\left(y\right)}{\cos^2\left(\theta\right)}+\frac{\sin\left(x\right)\:\sin\left(y\right)}{\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}$$

Options:

(a)2     (b)0     (c)1     (d)-1

****Solution given in my guide:****

***From Hypothesis***:

$sin\left(x+θ\right)=sin\left(y+θ\right)$

***Therefore***

$2cos\left(\frac{x+y+2θ}{2}\right)sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)=0$

***Now***
$x-y\ne 2n\pi \:\:⇒\:sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\ne \:0$  //How does this step work?

Hence

$\frac{x+y+2θ}{2}=\left(2n+1\right)\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$

$x+y=\left(2n+1\right)\pi -2θ$

And proceeds to the final answer as -1.

Comment: Do we know that $x\neq y$?

Comment: if x=y the expression simplifies to 1, not -1, so it must be in the problem statement that x is not equal to y or the question is flawed

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Using [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution),

$$\frac{1-\tan^2\dfrac x2}{\left(1+\tan^2\dfrac x2\right)\cos\theta}+\frac{2\tan\dfrac x2}{\left(1+\tan^2\dfrac x2\right)\sin\theta}=1$$

On rearrangement we have a Quadratic Equation in $\tan\dfrac x2$

We shall reach the same equation for $y$

Hence $\tan\dfrac x2,\tan\dfrac y2$ are the roots of the  Quadratic Equation

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\cos x}{\cos\theta}+\frac{\sin x}{\sin\theta}=1\iff\sin\theta\cos\theta=\cos x\sin\theta+\sin x\cos\theta$$

$$\iff\sin x\cos\theta=\sin\theta(\cos\theta-\cos x)$$

Squaring we get, $$(1-\cos^2x)\cos^2\theta=\sin^2\theta(\cos^2\theta+\cos^2x-2\cos\theta\cos x)$$

$$\iff\cos^2x-2\sin^2\theta\cos\theta\cos x+(\sin^2\theta-1)\cos^2\theta=0\ \ \ \ (1)$$

If we start with $\displaystyle\frac{\cos y}{\cos\theta}+\frac{\sin y}{\sin\theta}=1;$ we shall reach at the same equation.

So, the roots of $(1)$ are $\displaystyle\cos x,\cos y\implies\cos x\cos y=\frac{(\sin^2\theta-1)\cos^2\theta}1=-\cos^4\theta$

Similarly if we start with $$\frac{\cos x}{\cos\theta}+\frac{\sin x}{\sin\theta}=1\iff\cos\theta(\sin\theta-\sin x)=\cos x\sin\theta,$$

we shall reach at  $\displaystyle\sin x\sin y=-\sin^4\theta$

You should take it home from here

Comment: @user161425, How about this?  See also:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805602/how-to-to-a-better-approach-for-this

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, If $\displaystyle\cos x=\cos y,-\cos^4\theta=\cos^2x\iff \cos\theta=\cos x=0$  for real $x,\theta$ . From the first line of Question, can't we safely assume $\cos\theta\cdot\sin\theta\ne0$?